# Json schema showing directory names along with file schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a directory like this which contains the JSON file

```
/user/myuser/check/database=helloworld/table=program/proc_dt=2017-04-04/part-00000
```

The json file schema content as follows:

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/myuser/check/database=helloworld/table=program/proc_dt=2017-04-04/part-00000
```

> {"job_type":"Producer","person_id":"7d422349554","order":"1","entity_id":"123"}
>   {"job_type":"Producer","person_id":"af7dc39bc","order":"3","entity_id":"f2323"}

when I try to read the schema from the JSON file using below commands, I am getting the names of the directory also in the schema.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
var flattenedDatasetPath = "/user/myuser/check/database=helloworld/table=program/proc_dt=2017-04-04/"
var flattenedFileSchemaList = ArrayBuffer[String]()
val flattenedDataSetDF = sqlContext.read.json(flattenedDatasetPath)
var fieldNamesArr=flattenedDataSetDF.schema.fields
for(f<-fieldNamesArr){
    println(f.name)
    flattenedFileSchemaList+=f.name
}
```

This is the output which I get

```
entity_id
job_type
order
person_id
database
table
proc_dt
```

Why the directory names are coming as part of schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled` is set to `true` by default in Spark.

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", "false")
```

> The data types of the partitioning columns are automatically inferred.
>   Currently, numeric data types and string type are supported. Sometimes
>   users may not want to automatically infer the data types of the
>   partitioning columns. For these use cases, the **automatic type
>   inference can be configured by
>   spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled**, which is
>   **default to true**. When type inference is disabled, string type will be
>   used for the partitioning columns.

[Apache doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery)

Comment: The property is meant to hide the datatypes of the partitioning col. I have spark 1.5.2 version. Is there any way to hide the directory discovery. As per the doc, its going to come only in version 1.6
"Starting from Spark 1.6.0, partition discovery only finds partitions under the given paths by default."

Comment: It supports in 1.5.2 as well. the link I added is of the same version.

Comment: I tried with the property set to false, but still its reading the directory names. Its mentioned in the doc that the property "  spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled" is meant for the datatype but not for the col discovery.